# PIP Install lpod fails Error 1 and Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, git, debian, pip, lpod

I have Debian/Cinnamon and I'm trying to install the python lpod-python package so I can open LibreOffice files from Python 3.4. Python 2.7 and Idle 3 are also installed.

When I try

```
pip3 install lpod-python
```

it fails. I've read all the other answers to pip install with error code 1 and I'm sure pip and setuptools are correctly installed and up to date, so something else is wrong.

```
ed@eddebian:~$ pip3 install lpod-python
Downloading/unpacking lpod-python
  Downloading lpod-python-1.1.6.tar.gz (1.6MB): 1.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-r0wgfnfi/lpod-python/setup.py) egg_info for package lpod-python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-r0wgfnfi/lpod-python/setup.py", line 35, in <module>
        from release import has_git, get_release
      File "/tmp/pip-build-r0wgfnfi/lpod-python/release.py", line 92
        print get_release()
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-r0wgfnfi/lpod-python/setup.py", line 35, in <module>

    from release import has_git, get_release

  File "/tmp/pip-build-r0wgfnfi/lpod-python/release.py", line 92

    print get_release()

                    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-r0wgfnfi/lpod-python
```

I next tried cloning lpod from git and ran setup.py from the command line. I get the same syntax error but not the error code 1.

I presently have a work-around by converting the .odt files to text but it would boost my productivity considerably if I could read them straight into python. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your project use Python 3 or Python 2.6? 
If it uses Python 2.6, just do a

```
    pip install lpod-python
```

If it uses Python 3, you cannot use this library as it is not compatible with Python 3, which you can see by the

```
    print get_release()
```

being shown as syntax error, since print() is the correct syntax for Python3.

Comment: Thank you for both for your answers. I'd chosen Python 3 because it has (to my mind) a better approach to unicode which I need for special characters. So far I'm managing with the workaround and waiting for lpod to be upgraded

Answer (score 0):

That code would only work on Python 2; that library is clearly not compatible with Python 3.